# How do I take a list and add it as a column to an existing dataframe of a different length?

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I am trying to take a list and turn it into a new column in a dataframe of a different length. However, upon first attempt, it did not work due to the list and dataframe being different lengths. When I rearranged, it appears to have successfully pasted the list contents into a new dataframe, but instead of displaying the values, it only shows NULL. I conducted a similar process for list "formatted equations" successfully, but this does not work for list "predicted y". I believe that the problem lies with the "Type" where "formatted equations" is character, and "predicted y" is double, but am unsure how this problem arose and how to fix it.

I have a df containing rows of observations for various species. I fitted a linear regression for each species.

```
df_new <- int.df 
unique_species <- unique(df_new$species) 
lm_results <- list()
for (species_value in unique_species) {
  subset_df <- df_new[df_new$species == species_value, ]
  lm_model <- lm(canopy_area ~ height, data = subset_df)
  lm_results[[species_value]] <- lm_model
}
lm_results
```

I now have a list of lm_results in the following format.

```
$SENCAR - Senna cardiosperma
Call:lm(formula = canopy_area ~ height, data = subset_df)
# Coefficients:(Intercept)       height-3.252        4.106
$ERELAG - Eremophila latrobei ssp. glabra (Crimson Emubush)
Call:lm(formula = canopy_area ~ height, data = subset_df)
# Coefficients:(Intercept)       height-0.3018       1.3154
```

I then formatted these equations in the form y = c + mx, and created a new column in the original dataframe with the values.

```
# Initialize a list to store the formatted equations
formatted_equations <- list()
# Loop through each linear model and format the equation
for (i in seq_along(lm_results)) {model <- lm_results[[i]]
# Extract coefficients
intercept <- coef(model)[1]slope <- coef(model)[2]
# Format the equation
equation <- paste("y =", round(intercept, 2), "+", round(slope, 2), "x")

# Store the formatted equation
formatted_equations[[i]] <- equation}
for (i in seq_along(formatted_equations)) {cat("Species", unique_species[i], ":", formatted_equations[[i]], "\n")}
# Get the unique species values
unique_species <- unique(df_new$species)

# Create a named vector of equations
equations <- setNames(formatted_equations, unique_species)
#Add the equations to the original dataframe
df_new$equation <- equations[df_new$species]
# Display the updated dataframe with equations
# head(df_new)
```

I now want to do something very simple, which is input the x value as 2 into each linear regression and return the y value.

```
x_value = 2
new_data <- data.frame(height = x_value)
predicted_y <- lapply(lm_results, function(model){predict(model, newdata = new_data)})
predicted_y
```

This works, and returns the following:

```
$EREGLA - Eremophila glabra (Black fuchsia, tar bush)12.841173
$ACAANA - Acacia aneura var. aneura (Mulga)113.15732
```

etc.

But when I try to put this in a new column, all the values are NULL.

```
area_at_2m <- setNames(equations, unique_species)
# Add the area at 2m to the original dataframe
df_new$area_at_2m <- area_at_2m[df_new$species]
# Display the updated dataframe with values
head(df_new)
```

As requested, here are the results of running:

```
dput(head(df_new))
```

```
structure(list(site = c("B108VEG", "B108VEG", "B108VEG", "B108VEG", 
"B108VEG", "B108VEG"), species = c("EREGLA", "EREGLA", "EREGLA", 
"EREGLA", "EREGLA", "EREGLA"), height = c(1, 0.6, 1.3, 1.8, 1.4, 
0.8), width = c(1.4, 1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 1, 1.1), canopy_area = c(1.539380400259, 
1.13097335529233, 1.76714586764426, 2.26980069221863, 0.785398163397448, 
0.950331777710913), density_for_20_per_ha = c(130, 177, 114, 
89, 255, 211), equation = list(`EREGLA - Eremophila glabra (Black fuchsia, tar bush)` = "y = -0.2 + 1.52 x", 
    `EREGLA - Eremophila glabra (Black fuchsia, tar bush)` = "y = -0.2 + 1.52 x", 
    `EREGLA - Eremophila glabra (Black fuchsia, tar bush)` = "y = -0.2 + 1.52 x", 
    `EREGLA - Eremophila glabra (Black fuchsia, tar bush)` = "y = -0.2 + 1.52 x", 
    `EREGLA - Eremophila glabra (Black fuchsia, tar bush)` = "y = -0.2 + 1.52 x", 
    `EREGLA - Eremophila glabra (Black fuchsia, tar bush)` = "y = -0.2 + 1.52 x"), 
    area_at_2m = structure(list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL), names = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The only thing is that both lists are different, but I'm not sure why? See attached screenshots. [predicted_y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Nap.png) [formatted_equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ0jg.png)

I believe it's something to do wrong with type varying from character to double, but can't work out how to resolve this.

Comment: hi ncb! welcome to stack overflow. Can you run `dput(head(df_new))` and add it to your question? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like it could be done more automatically with dplyr + broom: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html